# cURL error 6: Could not resolve host when importing contacts

Tags: import, civicrm.settings.php

I recently updated CiviCRM in Drupal 7 from version 5.17.3 to 5.42.1

Now when I try to import contacts, I get to final step and click "import now". After a few seconds that I see the popup with "importing records" I get the following error:

cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: 320RK93TB985 (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

```
    #0 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php(1587): civicrm_api3("Contact", "create", (Array:17))
#1 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php(633): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->createContact((Array:13), (Array:36), "4", NULL, TRUE, "1")
#2 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser.php(196): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->import("4", (Array:25), NULL)
#3 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/ImportJob.php(233): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser->run("civicrm_tmp_d_dflt_68a71677e392d1db8155657ca45c97c2", (Array:22), 8, 1, "_id", "_status", "4", "0ea8ff7d03ae43f35391c591657e5d6a", 16, NULL, 30, NULL, "1")
#4 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Form/Preview.php(254): CRM_Contact_Import_ImportJob->runImport(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview))
#5 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(527): CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview->postProcess()
#6 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#7 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(43): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next", "Next")
#8 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next")
#9 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next")
#10 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(352): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#11 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(313): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#12 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#13 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#14 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(458): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#15 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("import", "contact")
#16 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#17 /mnt/www/html/vitintranetp3xtagv7qp/docroot/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#18 {main}
```

The only thing I changed during the upgrade is in the cicivcrm.settings.php where the old CiviCRM root variable wasn't finding the path to jQuery and JavaScript files and I had to change it to `sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/` instead of `/var/www/html/site_name/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/civicrm/` (where instead of site_name there is the name of my site).

Could this change cause the error? Everything else in CiviCRM seems to work fine.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have geocoding turned on or maybe some kind of postal address service? Also it's strange you would have to change civicrm_root that way, but I note that before it started with `var` whereas in the log message it looks like `mnt`. Are mnt and var aliases for each other?

Comment: Hi @Demerit thank you for your reply! I can try using mnt maybe? I don't know exactly if var is an alias becuase it was always set up (not by me) like that and I never had any problems. I am hosting the site in Acquia so I will clarify that part with them. How do I check if geocoding is turned on? I don't use any postal address services.

Comment: @Demerit I actually had an address standardization provider!! I was totally unaware of it! I found it under Administer->Localisation->Address Settings. thank you so much!! Just out of curiosity, how did you know that could be a problem?

Comment: I guessed becaused the error is about making a remote network call and the log shows it failing at the point where it creates/updates a contact, and I know that geocoding and address lookups are two things that use remote network calls and that happen when creating/updating contacts.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments the problem was an address standardization provider lookup failing.